# Bottleneck in gigabit LAN between samba server and laptop

Tags: networking, lan, samba, smb, internet-speed

I've got an ubuntu samba server running in my house which supports gigabit it's connected to a powerline communications adapter (also supports gigabit) then goes to my gigabit switch. When transferring from my laptop over ethernet I can get a maximum of 7 MB/s, I just got the gigabit switch, it was a 100mbit before but I got the same transfer speeds with the old on. Shouldn't I be getting 10 times as much?

Htop shows when transferring that it barely uses any processor power <1% and about 300MB RAM and it has 4GB of ecc memory.

I used dd to check the disk write speed on the server and it's about 80MB/s.

So why am I getting such a slow transfer rates?

---

edit 1

Writing a file from server to laptop is even slower, only just slightly. Which seems weird because the laptop sports an SSD and I thought it would be the hard disk to be the bottleneck.

---

edit 2

I tried transferring with winscp to see if the smb protocol was the bottleneck but speeds remain about the same

I will try the transfer again but without the plc between server and switch but later since it's quite a heavy server hidden away.

Comment: Please provide model and make of your "powerline communications adapter". I suspect it "supporting" GbE could mean that it has one GbE port, but it doesn't actually reach that speed. To verify my assumption, I'd like to read the manual. My assumption isn't baseless, because I have two devices at home "supporting GbE" and both of them reach only 5MB/s, which is less than 10Mbit/s. These are early WD MyBook.

Comment: It's the ZyXel PLA5256 [link](https://www.zyxel.com/products_services/1000-Mbps-Powerline-Pass-Thru-2-Port-Gigabit-Ethernet-Adapter-PLA5256/)

Comment: On the page you linked, they say `delivers wired speed of up to 1000 Mbps*` further down you can see what the asterisk means: `* The theoretical maximum channel data transfer rate is derived from HomePlug AV2 specifications. Actual data transfer rate will vary from network environment including: distance, network traffic, noise on electrical wires, quality of electrical installation and other adverse conditions.` If you could test this apparatus in the same room and see if something changes? Or connect them to one power strip and test the transfer in this case?